# How to capture each changes in v$session in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to capture each and every changes happen to `v$session` table?

The `active session history` does not have every bits of changes. I tried to write a PL/SQL block that will copy everything of `v$session` table to another table each second. But, one second is still too long as I am missing out many active / inactive / kill status changes.

Is it possible to write something similar to trigger that will copy the changes when any insert / update / delete happens?
I tried to create trigger on `v$session`, but it looks like triggers like those can not be created for views like `v$session`.

Basically what I am looking for is any way to capture all the changes in `v$session`.

With that, I am planning to do some trend analysis to identify session behaviors.

Any help?

PS: Can somebody tell what is the refresh rate of `v$session`? With that info, if I capture everything within the time interval of the refresh rate, I should be able to capture all the changes I believe.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`V$SESSION` is built on top of `X$` tables therefore there is no refresh rate. `X$` tables are mapped to Oracle memory structures. So it always shows current data, there is no read consistency model.

`V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` samples all sessions basically every second. And by default every 10th sample is persisted in Automatic Workload Repository and `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY`.

If you are interested in session status changes, there are database level triggers for connect and disconnect actions as well as DDL triggers so you can detect `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION` too.